# Closed form of $\sum^\infty_{n=0} \binom{n+2}{n} \log(1+ a q^n)$.

Tags: summation, closed-form

I would like to know whether the sum
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=0}\binom{n+2}{n}\log(1+a\ q^n) \quad \text{ with } \quad 0<a<1 \text{ and } |q|<1
\end{align}
has a closed form or not. The logarithm here is the natural logarithm. This is not quite the [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) because of the $a$ and the positive sign in front of $q^n$. My hope is that someone could direct me to some known special function. Many thanks.

Update: Without the binomial coefficient it seems that we have what some called the [q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol#:%7E:text=The%20q%2DPochhammer%20symbol%20is,theory%20of%20generalized%20hypergeometric%20series.).

Comment: You need $|q|<1$ (or $a=0$) for this to converge.

Comment: @J.G. Ah yes. Let's assume $|q|<1$, otherwise the problem is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

It could be interesting to compare with the integral since
\begin{align*}&\frac{1}{2}\int (n+1) (n+2) \log \left(1+a q^n\right)\,dn\\ &= \frac{-\left(n+1)(n+2\right) \log ^2(q) \text{Li}_2\left(-a q^n\right)-2
   \text{Li}_4\left(-a q^n\right)+(2 n+3) \log (q) \text{Li}_3\left(-a
   q^n\right)}{2 \log ^3(q)},\end{align*}
\begin{align*}&\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty (n+1) (n+2) \log \left(1+a q^n\right)\,dn \\ & =\frac{2 \text{Li}_2(-a) \log ^2(q)-3 \text{Li}_3(-a) \log (q)+2
   \text{Li}_4(-a)}{2 \log ^3(q)}.\end{align*}

For a quick check : $a=\frac 12$ and $q=\frac 34$ leads to $30.5249$ while the infinite summation gives $30.6846$

Comment: Adding $\frac{3}{8}\log (1 + a) - \frac{a}{{12(1 + a)}}\log (q)$ may improve the accuracy.

Comment: @Gary. It improves a lot ! But, where this is coming from ?

Comment: They come from the first two correction terms of the Euler–Maclaurin formula.

Comment: @Gary. My God ! Shame on me. I think that I am becoming too old.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for the answer. But I am hoping to find something more exact.

Comment: @kaiCheong. Use what Gary wrote in comments.